# password validation on specific characters in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, validation

I have to validate the password and confirm password fields. I also have to show on which fields their characters do not match. This is the code I have so far without the characters check.

```js
function checkPaswd(){
    
    if (document.getElementById('pass1').value !== "" && document.getElementById('ppass').value !== "")
            {if(document.getElementById("pass1").value == document.getElementById("ppass").value){
              document.getElementById('msg').style.color = 'green';
              document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = 'matching';
     }
    
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById('msg').style.color = 'red';
            document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = 'not matching';
    }
    
    }
```

```html
    <form id="pass-form">
     Password:
     <input name="pass1" id="pass1" type="password" pattern=".{10,}" placeholder="Password" required onkeyup="checkPaswd(); return false;" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Password is not 10+ characters');" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('');">
     
     Confirm Password:
     <input name="ppass" id="ppass" type="password" pattern=".{10,}" placeholder="Confirm Password" required onkeyup="checkPaswd(); return false;" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Password not empty');" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('');">
     <span id="msg"></span>
     </form>
```

Comment: So are you asking why you always have the red input field instantly after you filled one of the password field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all try to save your variables against redundancy, e.g. `var pass2 = document.getElementById('pass1').value;`.

Then you could get each character at the specific index of your string with `String.charAt(index)`. So you could simply iterate over your passwords with a for loop from `i = 0` to `String.length` and see in which indexes there is a mismatch. Depending on what you want to return, it could be simply a boolean for any mismatch, or an array of mismatch indexes...

PS. I'd recommend before that check if the lengths of both passwords match!

Good luck!

Comment: I added this to my code but it does not work. Have I made any mistakes?          else {  if (pass.length == pass2.length) {
  for (i = 0; i < pass.length; i++){
     if (pass.charAt(i) !== pass2.charAt(i))
     document.getElementById('msg').style.color = 'red';
     document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = 'don't match on' + " " + i;
      }  
    }

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?
The syntax is correct, try to debug the part and see what happens step by step. If you don't know how to debug a js core in browser then see: “Learn How To Debug JavaScript with Chrome DevTools” @BrandonMorelli https://codeburst.io/learn-how-to-debug-javascript-with-chrome-devtools-9514c58479db